# Edit a Single Core Data Entry Rather than All Entries with the Same Attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview, editing

I have a partially working app but am in need of some assistance to get this over the edge. I am trying to edit a single core data object, rather than all objects with the same attribute. This will make sense shortly.

I have a table view controller which has a plus button in the navigation bar; the user clicks it and is presented with a Modal View with 4 text fields: name, event, date and amount. The user adds in this information, presses save and it gets saved to the Core Data database.

I have the following model:
Transaction 
Occasion (title attribute)
Item (amountType attribute)
Date (dateOEvent attribute)
Person (name attribute)

Transaction has a relationship to Occasion, Item, Date and Person.

The app is working very well now when I save new entries; there are no duplicates and it's working well. The tableview controller is set to display the Transactions in the cells and sections with NSFetchedResultsController, so by using the relationships, I can for example set the `cell.textLabel.text = transaction.whoBy.name`.

When it comes to editing the transactions, here is where there is a slight but serious issue. I click on a cell in the table view and through prepareForSegue, it successfully passes me to a new view controller with the text fields already populated with the information from the cell I clicked on. The problem comes with editing.

If my Table view has 3 entries for Jack and 1 entry for Mary with all the information filled in, like the event title, the date of the event, the amount, etc. That works because in 3 separate cells in the Table view, I see Jack, but with different events, amounts and dates for each of "Jack's" transactions. So:

Cell 1 (name - event - date - amount):
Jack - BBQ - Today - 400

Cell 2:
Jack - Kid - July - 500

Cell 3: 
Jack - New House - July - 1000

Cell 4:
Mary - Holiday - October - 400

What I want is to click on Cell 1 and change JACK to JOHN. The problem I have now is, with the code you'll see below, if I change Jack to John, cell 1, 2 AND 3 also get changed to John and that is clearly not what I want.

My Detail View Controller for the editing has a `Transaction *transaction` property so it can set the information passed over from the Table view, and in the `viewDidLoad`, I have the following, where `self.oldName` is just a NSString property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.editingNameTextField.text = self.selectedTransaction.whoBy.name;
    self.oldName = self.editingNameTextField.text;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The Edit Entry Save Method is like this:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    self.selectedTransaction.whoBy.name = self.oldName;
    Person *person = [Person personWithName:self.oldName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    self.selectedTransaction.whoBy = person;
    self.selectedTransaction.whoBy.name = self.editingNameTextField.text;

    // Same code for Occasion, removed for brevity

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

That calls the method personWithName:

```
+ (Person *)personWithName:(NSString *)name inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Person *person = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the name of the person already exists
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *people = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!people)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else if (![people count])
    {
        // If the person count is 0 then let's create it
        person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        person.name = name;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the object exists, just return the last object .
        person = [people lastObject];
    }
    return person; 
}
```

I have to do the same for the Occasion and Date, but my question is starting with the Person, how do I edit a SINGLE transaction in the Table View (the selected Transaction) rather than renaming EVERY name. I just want to edit Cell 1's name text field from Jack to John and have the other cells still remain showing Jack, etc.

Any help would once again be massively appreciated!

Comment: do you have 1 jack or 3 jacks in your core data database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have 1 jack in the core data database, because when I'm adding a new entry, if "Jack" is the name typed in, it doesn't create a new jack, it simply references and returns the Jack that already exists - however in this case, I want to edit just the single transaction object.. so my thinking is, each object has a uniqueID, could I not just find that transaction ID and edit that, etc? or is there a better way to do this

Comment: When changing the name, you will need to determine if it is a new name, and if so create a new Person and set it's relationships (date & occasion) from the old person to the new person. If the name already exists, then you need to move the relationships to the other already existing person. What is happening now is you are changing the existing person's name, which results in what you are experiencing now.

Comment: Hi @bobnoble - thank you very much for the reply and that makes sense - I now can piece together why this is happening with the existing person's name attribute which changes it everywhere.. would you be able to possibly provide some sample code based on my code above on how I would go about moving the relationships, etc? I understand it theoretically but have no clue how to implement it technically because I can see I have code which already does the checking if new name, or existing name - I just need that moving the relationship over.. thanks!

Comment: then i really dont understand your data modell... so in the example the 3 jacks are the same person? if so, why changing only one name. if not so, why only one object in your database? each jack should be a seperate object...

Comment: The problem with each Jack being a separate object is that when I go to the Person Tab (which shows just the names using predates), it shows Jack three separate times. The app works very well with the multiple entries for a single name right now, but when I edit a transaction and a name, I want to edit that particular NAME for that transaction rather than every occurrence of that name.. @bobnoble's message was exactly what I want to achieve - I just have no idea how to in code

Comment: @bobnoble Do you have any indication on how the code could possibly look? Thanks

Comment: Assuming the Person entity has a one-to-many relationship with a Transaction entity, set the Transaction's `whoBy` to the new Person object (or the existing Person in the case the Person with the given name already exists).

Comment: @bobnoble - Thanks for the reply and absolutely, a one-to-many relationship with Transaction Entity from Person. I think I'm doing that, setting the Transaction's WhoBy to the new Person or am very close to doing that? (code in the question)   self.selectedTransaction.whoBy.name = self.oldName;
    Person *person = [Person personWithName:self.oldName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    self.selectedTransaction.whoBy = person;
    self.selectedTransaction.whoBy.name = self.editingNameTextField.text; - is that not correct?

Comment: @bobnoble sorry - the text was hard to read in that - In my question, the code I use in the save method for the editing is there.. I'm happy to change this to anything - I feel like I'm so close!